# HTML5 video not playing on IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, html5-video

Im trying to use HTML5 video on IE9 but doesn't play.

When i play it locally evrything works fine, but when i upload to the server doesn't work.
This is the URL: http://inoq.com/lxgo2/monumentos.html
It works fine in all other browsers(Chrome, Safari, Opera, Firefox..) just not IE9.

I already added the mime types too .htaccess file:
AddType video/ogg                      ogv
AddType video/mp4                      mp4 m4v
AddType video/webm                     webm

This image shows the network logs on IE9: 
[Network logs IE9 http://inoq.com/lxgo2/network-log.jpg](http://inoq.com/lxgo2/network-log.jpg)

Any idea on what can be the problem?

Thanks
Bruno